# Transform object to array of objects with custom keys

Tags: underscore.js

Just want to know if there is any better and simple way to transform object to array of objects using underscoreJS. Below is what i have tried.

http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/VGc9E/

```

```
    var newArr = []
    _.each(toBeUpdated, function(value, key) {
        var newObj = {};
        newObj.field = key;
        newObj.fieldstatus = value;
        newArr.push(newObj);
    });

    console.log(newArr);
```

```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You don't want to manually create a new array and `.push()` to it, you just want to [**map**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) over your objects using [`_.map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map):

```
var newArr = _.map(toBeUpdated, function(value, key) {
    return {field: key, fieldstatus: value};
});
```